# Does Flink provide Java API to submit jobs to JobManager?

Tags: java, apache-flink, distributed-computing, flink-streaming

I know Jobs can be submit to JobManager by flink or flink.bat. I wanna know whether Flink provides Java API to submit jobs to JobManager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Depending on the type of cluster you want to connect, there are several implementations of the ClusterClient (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/ClusterClient.html).

It can run jobs either in a blocking (synchronous) or detached (asynchronous) fashion. One way of deploying a job is to provide a PackagedProgram, which consists of a JAR file with a Main Class and several supporting JAR files (additional libraries required specifically for the job).

Comment: But I don't see any method in ClusterClient to specify the JobManager address. Could you tell me how to specify the address?

Answer (score 3):

You can look at this test class [ClientTest.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-clients/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/ClientTest.java), may be able to help you, more configuration parameters see [configuration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/config.html#jobmanager-amp-taskmanager).